# Attempting to save a snapshot complains Application not found

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to save an App snapshot on OpenShift, however it complains that my application isn't found. When I type `rhc apps` my application is correctly listed, not sure what I could be doing wrong.

For example:

```
appname @ http://appname-domain.rhcloud.com
```

when I run `rhc snapshot save -a appname`, I get:

```
Application 'appname' not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is not in your default namespace, then you will need to add the -n option to your rhc snapshot save command.  That could be your issue.

Comment: Ah-ha! I knew it was something simple. I only have one namespace but this wasn't the original that was created. Thank you!